# Как сделать горизонтальный scroll для элемента, а не для всего документа?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть scroll страницы зажатием курсора мыши. Сам scroll делается этой частью кода:

```
var dragHandler = {
                lastClientX: 0,

                start: function (e) {
                    console.log('start');


                        if (e.button == 0) {
                            console.log('start button == 0');
                            scroller_content.addEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler.drag);
                            dragHandler.lastClientX = e.clientX;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } 

                },
                end: function (e) {
                    console.log('end');
                        if (e.button == 0) {
                            console.log('end button == 0');
                            scroller_content.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler.drag);                        
                        } 

                },
                drag: function (e) {

                    if($('.scroller-kanban-content').hasClass('scroller-active')){
                        var delta = e.clientX - dragHandler.lastClientX;
                        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX - delta, window.scrollY);
                        dragHandler.lastClientX = e.clientX;
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }

                }
            };
            scroller_content.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler.start);
            scroller_content.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler.end);
```

Но нужно чтобы работало только для определенного заданного элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример для элемента:

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.scroll-box');
box.scrollTo( box.scrollLeft + 500, box.scrollTop );
```

```css
.scroll-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.in {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-box">
  <div class="in">
  Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: весь код вывел, ваш пример почему-то не сработал